# Is possible to change the size of a Rich-Faces dialog dynamically?

Tags: richfaces, modal-dialog

[image]

I have in mind to create a dialog as the image, with 3 toggle panels, but I desire that everytime the toggle panels are shown/hide the dialog size changes.

Is this possible using Rich-Faces dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

Both `rich:modalPanel` and `rich:popupPanel` have an `autosized` attribute, set it to true and it will do what you want. E.g.

```
<rich:popupPanel id="panel" autosized="true">
    <rich:collapsiblePanel …
    <rich:collapsiblePanel …
    …
</rich:popupPanel>
```